# 'Corrupted double-linked list' memory errors - OpenCV-Python 3.0.0 and Numpy on ARM

Tags: python, c++, c, opencv, numpy

I'm using OpenCV 3.0.0-dev and Numpy 1.8.2 on an NVIDIA Jetson TK1 developer board (based on ARM). I compiled OpenCV from source, and install python-numpy using apt-get. I have Python 2.7.6.

I've been running into memory corruption problems:

```
*** Error in `python': corrupted double-linked list: 0x008f2fb8 ***
```

This appears inconsistently. Sometimes it is at a 'cap.read()', sometimes a 'np.zeros()' call will trigger it, or sometimes it can be reproduced by writing rotation and translation vectors from 'solvePnP()' to variables with a value of None. For example:

If rvec and tvec are the outputs of solvePnP:

```
var = None
var2 = None
var = rvec
var2 = tvec
```

will sometimes cause the error. Infrequently, just accessing rvec and tvec will cause it.

This seems to be a problem in NumPy, because of the fact that np.zeros can produce it and that has nothing to do with OpenCV.

Here's a gdb traceback of one case of the problem.

```
*** Error in `/usr/bin/python': corrupted double-linked list: 0x008eb8c8 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__libc_do_syscall () at ../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/libc-do-syscall.S:44
44  ../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/libc-do-syscall.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __libc_do_syscall () at ../ports/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/libc-do-syscall.S:44
#1  0xb66e4f0e in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#2  0xb66e7766 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#3  0xb670bbf0 in __libc_message (do_abort=<optimized out>, fmt=0xb678d084 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#4  0xb671279e in malloc_printerr (action=1, str=0xb678d0c8 "corrupted double-linked list", ptr=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:4996
#5  0xb6713492 in _int_free (av=0xb67a24e8 <main_arena>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3996
#6  0x00063efe in list_dealloc.18562 (op=0xa7d21da0) at ../Objects/listobject.c:311
#7  0x0006458a in frame_dealloc.16591 (
f=Frame 0xa7c97208, for file sf.py, line 169, in track (frame_descrs=<numpy.ndarray at remote 0x8ee8c8>, target=<ARTarget(name='', url='', image=<numpy.ndarray at remote 0x732870>, keypoints=[<cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95e08>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95e30>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95e58>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95e80>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95ea8>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95ed0>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95ef8>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95f20>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95f48>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95f70>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95f98>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c95fc0>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c9c020>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c9c048>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c9c070>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c9c098>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c9c0c0>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c9c0e8>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c9c110>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c9c138>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c9c160>, <cv2.KeyPoint at remote 0xa7c9c188>, <cv2.KeyPoint at rem...(truncated)) at ../Objects/frameobject.c:460
```

Line 169 of sf.py is as follows:

```
dist_coef = np.zeros(4)
```

To me, it looks like there's a problem when NumPy tries to allocate or deallocate memory. The system isn't running out of RAM, though...

**EDIT:** This code does not reproduce the error, oddly:

```
import numpy as np
while True:
    dist_coef = np.zeros(4)
```

Does this suggest that some Numpy variables/arrays used in the program are somehow corrupting others?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with the pre-built numpy binary - have you tried compiling it from source?

Comment: Yes - I tried building Numpy 1.8.2 from source. The same error occurs.

Comment: Did you see any errors during compilation? Does it fail any of the unittests (`import numpy as np; np.test()`)?

Comment: No, there were no errors during comilation. All of the unittests pass.

Comment: In which case you should definitely raise an issue on the [numpy GitHub repo](https://github.com/numpy/numpy). Based on the fact that the unittests all pass, and that [they currently don't do Travis CI builds for ARM anyway](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/265fbe15cb4c34e4d54c672582657a11ed52af8b/.travis.yml), your problem may have slipped by unnoticed by the numpy devs for some time. I'm afraid I don't know enough about numpy's internals to give any more guidance.

Comment: It would be very helpful for narrowing down the cause if you could make a minimal example that reproduces the error using only numpy and not OpenCV

Answer (score 1):

You should check your RAM. Install memtest86 , reboot into it, and let it run for several hours.

Most Linux distributions have a package for the free version [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) but it is unclear if this works well on UEFI systems, in case you may use the proprietary [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/technical.htm).